# Change value on Text Input in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, setstate

I am trying to update the value of input text after HTTP POST response is received from server. PFB my code detail, let me know what I am doing wrong here or guide me through any demo.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, changeState, setState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext, Onboarding, Form, Message, useAPI } from 'components/lib';
import Axios from 'axios';    

function Welcome() {
      const context = useContext(AuthContext);
      const postData = { user_id: context.user.user_id }
      const [items, setItems] = useState({
        business_name: "ABC"
      });
      useEffect( () =>  {
        const singleData = async () => {
          let response = await Axios.post( '/api/getbusiness', postData)
                 .then(res => {
                  setItems({
                    business_name: res.data.data.business_name
                  });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                })
        }
        singleData()
      },[])
    
      return (
        <Form
          data={
            business_name: {
              label: 'Business Name',
              type: 'text',
              required: true,
              errorMessage: 'Please enter business name',
              value: `${ items.business_name }`
            }
          }}
          url='/api/onboarding/1'
          method='POST'
          buttonText='Save'
          callback={ res => {
            console.log(res);
          }}
          />
    
      )
    }
```

At page load, input displays value "ABC", but after getting HTTP response `setItems` doesn't update the value in input field.

Comment: `setItems()` seems to only be called inside the initial `useEffect` (Which has no dependancies, so will only run on first mount) Where are you expecting it to be updated?

Comment: my http request outputs the business_name and I want to change the value of text input once response is received. the value "ABC" should be updated to the value of business_name param

Comment: What React package are you using for "Form" component?

Comment: @talent-jsdev I have updated the imports in questions

Comment: Have you ever logged the value of res.data.data.business_name after receiving a response?

Comment: yes, console.log(res.data.data.business_name) displays the name of business

Comment: Please try to update your useEffect block as follows:         
useEffect(() => {
            Axios.post('/api/getbusiness', postData)
                .then(res => {
                    setItems({
                        business_name: res.data.data.business_name
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }, [])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249596/discussion-between-talent-jsdev-and-devilism).

Answer (score 0):

you have `res.data.data.business_name` when it should just be `res.data.business_name`. Also in your form `input` you need to add a `defaultValue={items.business_name}` attribute display the response from your axios call.